# command line for putting bootable iso on usb

Tags: linux, iso, bootable

Is there a basic linux command line, that does not make use of any 3rd party software, that places a bootable .iso file onto a USB memory stick that is then bootable and will install said linux?

I have the rhel-8.1 iso but it is 7.6gb.

I am out of dual-layer dvd's and would like to use my 32gb USB stick to install rhel-8.1.

Last time I tried which I think was CentOS-7.7 having put that onto USB via my windows10 pc, it booted but I then ran into some *sata driver* errors during install.  And became really frustrated and just went back to dvd which worked.

Looking for a reliable, frustration-free, way to

- plug 32gb usb stick into pc running centos 7.7
- get the rhel-8.1 iso onto that usb stick and have that usb stick bootable

  - either by native command line
  - or using a free 3rd party software in linux, which i am ok with
- boot a UEFI pc having that bootable usb stick and **successfully** install rhel 8.1 (or any linux iso) onto a single SSD connected via SATA.

Comment: The utility you're looking for is called `cp`: `cp image.iso /dev/sdb` where `/dev/sdb` is the name of the drive.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk Glad you found it! _ron_ See https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/cp/ and https://superuser.com/questions/620877/cp-command-to-make-bootable-iso-image-usb

Comment: so do not partition the usb key but just straight copy `cp rhel-8.1-x86_64-dvd.iso /dev/sdb` to the block device?

Comment: Yes, but be careful and you use the correct device.

Comment: thanks, will try tonight.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk Do you wish to make a separate answer post? I'd suggest it.

Comment: I install grub in UEFI boot mode to flash drive. Or used to install in BIOS boot mode. Then create a grub.cfg to boot ISO. I normally create another partition with folder /ISO to hold all the ISO. Then can boot grub & choose ISO. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot 
examples
https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c
 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possibilities: `cat`, `dd`, `pv`, `cp`.

I think that `cp` is the easiest and should be available on each UNIX
and Linux system. Use it like that:

```
cp <iso_image> /dev/<disk_name>
```

Use a disk name such as `/dev/sdb`, not a partition such as
`/dev/sdb1`.  Make a backup of data on the disk you're copying to
because it will be replaced with contents of .iso image and be careful
to use a correct disk name to not inadvertently overwrite your
current filesystem.  You shouldn't need to be root because on today's
desktop Linux systems removable storage devices are owned by `plugdev`
and users are already members of that that group.

Comment: that worked like a champ, thanks.

Comment: a given usb stick will no longer be usable and re-formattable under microsoft windows.  To make it back to windows usable, in linux do `parted /dev/sd? mklabel gpt; parted /dev/sd? mkpart primary 0% 100%; mkfs.fat /dev/sd?` replacing `?` with the correct letter of the block device your usb stick is.  Then reformat in Windows with disk manager to make ntfs if desired.

Answer (score 2):

You'd think *dd* would be a good choice. Sorry, but https://askubuntu.com/questions/25476/how-to-make-a-usb-drive-bootable-after-live-image-is-copied-into-it-using-dd-c says it's not reliable for this use.

Therefore, in the absence of anything better documented, would you consider  using [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) which is designed to create a bootable Live USB drive?

Once installed, launch the app, and a menu appears. Select the Diskimage button and ISO should be chose in the spin box, then click on the triple dot box and browse to the location of your ISO file.

[image: unetbootin menu]

Make sure **not** to use persistence  ("Space used to preserve...") on the next to last line of the menu screen.

Comment: It doesn't look like a *command line* utility to me.

Comment: a simple one line command is preferred, but this is ok with me as long as it is free and it works.